# Center CSS Background fit to height

Tags: css, resize, center, alignment

first off here's my current code.

```
<div id="background">
<img src="src/1080pTux.png" height=100%>
</div>

#background{
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    z-index: -5000;

}
```

The image stays fit to height, maintains aspect ratio, and stays behind everything, but i want it positioned centered at all times. How can I accomplish that and what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't center using automatic margins when the position is set to fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try somthing like this:

```
body {
text-align: center;
min-width: 600px;
}
```

Even though it says text align it will align the whole page in the center since your modifying the whole body to be centered.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use [background-image](http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Comment: can't, I need to height to adjust to window and that's full screen.